# Disable write cache for exFAT partitions

Tags: mount, drivers, exfat

For context, I'm on kernel 6.1, so using post-5.7 in-tree exFAT kernel drivers.

Currently, if I plug in an exFAT-formatted flash drive and write to it, it will write to a RAM cache and flush to flash slowly. This is not great because to userspace applications (and therefore the user), it seems like writing has completed, until you try to unmount the drive (or more accurately, the partition) and `umount` (or `udisksctl`) hangs. What's worse is if the user is unaware of this behaviour and has the bad habit of not unmounting before unplugging, it just causes silent data corruption.

So I would very much like to disable this caching behaviour. From reading `man mount`, there's surprisingly no mention of exFAT at all. Under the "Mount options for fat" section, there is the `flush` option. But if I understand correctly, this section is not applicable to exFAT because exFAT is handled by the `exfat` driver, which is distinct from the `vfat` driver which handles the likes of FAT16 and FAT32.

Indeed, if I try to mount my exFAT partition using the `flush` option, it simply errors:

```bash
# sda1 is my exFAT partition
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1 -o flush
Error mounting /dev/sda1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.OptionNotPermitted: Mount option `flush' is not allowed
```

So is disabling write cache simply not supported by the `exfat` drivers currently? If no, are there any workarounds?

Comment: `mount -o sync` should work

Comment: @frostschutz I’m not sure the `exfat` driver supports that :-/

Comment: I'm also not sure, but it does use the IS_DIRSYNC macro and mounting it on a ramdisk with sync is slower than without, so it's doing something. That said, it's still a terrible idea to unplug without ejecting properly, and sync may also cause write amplification, and you might still suffer corruption regardless. (My personal impression is that exfat corrupts more easily than fat, anyway... but I don't know about implementation details)

Comment: @frostschutz right, I wrote that only after checking [`man mount`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) but that’s not conclusive. Looking at the source code, it definitely honours `IS_DIRSYNC` for sure (that’s `-o dirsync`), and I see it checks `SB_SYNCHRONOUS` and `IS_SYNC` (`-o sync`) in a couple of places, so it should be OK.

Comment: the mount manpage I have does not cover exfat at all yet